# After liking application not refreshing to application

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a php facebook application that requires that you like the page before getting access to photos [Free Cover Photos](http://www.facebook.com/freecoverphotos). The problem is after liking it not all browsers take you to the application. It requires you to refresh the browser to view. Any suggestions?

IE worked ok
FF needing refresh
Chrome needing refresh

Tested on several systems.

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you have the answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Chrome is working for me.  Maybe you have an older version of Chrome or some non-default setting turned on.  Try turning off all the plugins in Chrome and see it that helps...maybe one of them is getting in the way.